# Laravel compare database and api

Tags: php, laravel

I have api base data like:

```
array:21 [▼
  0 => "jne"
  1 => "pos"
  2 => "tiki"
  3 => "esl"
  4 => "pcp"
  5 => "rpx"
  6 => "cahaya"
  7 => "dse"
  8 => "first"
  9 => "indah"
  10 => "jet"
  11 => "jnt"
  12 => "ncs"
  13 => "pahala"
  14 => "pandu"
  15 => "sap"
  16 => "sicepat"
  17 => "slis"
  18 => "star"
  19 => "nss"
  20 => "wahana"
]
```

which i get with this code:

```
$cori = $rajaongkir->courier('all');
$cori =  array_keys($cori);
```

I also have database table named `couriers` where i saved `same names as you see in my dd above` + `status` and dd of my table is:

```
Collection {#825 ▼
  #items: array:19 [▼
    0 => "jne"
    1 => "pos"
    2 => "tiki"
    3 => "esl"
    4 => "rpx"
    5 => "cahaya"
    6 => "dse"
    7 => "first"
    8 => "indah"
    9 => "jet"
    10 => "jnt"
    11 => "ncs"
    12 => "pahala"
    13 => "pandu"
    14 => "sap"
    15 => "sicepat"
    16 => "slis"
    17 => "star"
    18 => "nss"
  ]
}
```

this is how i get that:

```
$selectedcouriers = Courier::where('active', '=', '1')->pluck('courier');
```

> PS: as you see my table dd has `2` names less than my api dd that's
>   because those 2 names active status is `0` (deactivated)

## Problem

what I try to do here is compare between my `API courier names` and my `Database courier names` (which are the same by the way) and then return only those couriers with status of `1` in my database (ignore the rest of courier names in my api)

how can i do this compare?

#### My full code is:

```
$cori = $rajaongkir->courier('all'); // get all couriers from api

$cori =  array_keys($cori); // retrieve only their names

$selectedcouriers = Courier::where('active', '=', '1')->pluck('courier'); // get my DB couriers with active status

//comparing code...?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, use `array_intersect()`

```
$result = array_intersect($selectedcourier, $cori);
```

Comment: i'm getting `array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array`

Comment: just add `toArray()` to convert collection object to array.

like `$selectedcouriers = Courier::where('active', '=', '1')->pluck('courier')->toArray();`

Comment: @mafortis `->toArray()` (its a collection, as you can see from the result of `dd()`.)

Comment: one last thing? i need to get it imploded by `:` like `"dse:jne:pos:tiki"` instead i have now like: `"0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17"
` with this code: `$lastresult = implode(':', array_keys($result));` any idea?